# On the coincidence of extremal and strong epimorphisms when $(Epi,Mono)$ is a factorization system

Tags: category-theory

Suppose that $(Epi,Mono)$ is a factorization system on a category $\mathfrak{A}$. It may be easily shown that every epimorphism is extremal. On the other hand, in every category, the implication strong epimorphism $\implies$ extremal always holds. Is it possible to say something on the reverse implications when $(Epi,Mono)$ is a factorization system on $\mathfrak{A}$. If not, which can be a possible counterexample?

Comment: Perhaps I confuse something, but once you have that $(Epi,Mono)$ is a factorization system, the orthogonality between $Epi$ and $Mono$ already means that every epimorphism is strong. In particular this holds for every extremal epimorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by factorisation system? Orthogonal? Or just any natural/functorial factorisation?

Comment: @ZhenLin I0m using Borceux' Definition of Factorization System. Marc Olschok answered to me and, in fact, he's right! As any epimorphism must be orthogonal to every monomorphism, we necessarily have that any epimorphism is strong.